# Select 80 chocolate from 5 different brands with a restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a counting problem:

***A child has been asked to pick 80 candies (in total) from 5 different brands of candies. he has to pick in a way that he gets at-least minimum of 10 candies from any 2 brands each. he can pick more. such that there are at least 2 brands from which 10 or more candies are picked?***

I think this type of problem could be solved with stars and bars method.

To choose indistinguishable item (n= 80) from k (5) distinguishable - we can solve this problem by arranging placeholders (*) and dividers (|)

There are C(n+k-1, n) ways to select 80 candies out of 5 distinguishable brands.
but I am not sure how can I ensure that he is picking up at least 10 candies each from any of the 2 brands?

Comment: Please show what you tried then only people will help you

Comment: I have added how far I have gotten with this problem.

Comment: please apply principle of inclusion exclusion

Comment: Is it at least $10$ candies each from  *any* two brands or from any two *particular* brands ?

Answer (score 1):

These type of problems are solved while considering different possible cases. Suppose A, B, C, D, & E are the 5 brands. 80 candies we have to pick.

***CASE 1*** - 2 brands

> 10 from each of the 2 brands. 20 done.
> For the rest of the 60. 0A,60B; 1A,59B; 2A;58B; ... 59A,1B; 60A,0B. (or C(n+k-1, n)). 81 possibilities.
> 2 out of 5 brands can be selected in 10 ways.

Hence, a total of 810 possibilities.

***CASE 2*** - 3 brands

> 10 from each of the 3 brands. 30 done.
> For the rest of the 50, use C(n+k-1, n). 22100 possibilities.
> 3 out of 5 brands can be selected in 10 ways.

Hence, a total of 221000 possibilities.

***CASE 3*** - 4 brands

> 10 from each of the 4 brands. 40 done.
> For the rest of the 40, use C(n+k-1, n). 123410 possibilities.
> 4 out of 5 brands can be selected in 5 ways.

Hence, a total of 617050 possibilities.

***CASE 4*** - 5 brands

> 10 from each of the 5 brands. 50 done.
> For the rest of the 30, use C(n+k-1, n).

Hence, a total of 556512 possibilities.

All of this gives us 1395372 different combinations of selecting 80 candies from 5 brands while having at least 10 candies from at least 2 different brands.